# String conversion to datetime independant of string format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I want to convert a string to datetime format.
The thing is that the string comes in different formats.
For instance, in the code below, strDate can be "2/20/2014 1:41:57 PM" or "20/02/2014 13:44:56".
Convert.ToDateTime(strDate) executes well just for one format (the one on the user browser settings) and generates an error for the other.
How can I successfully convert the string to datetime independently of the string format?
Thanks

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);
```

Comment: There is no way to automatically detect what date "2/5/2014 13:14:15" represents. Is it the second of may of the fifth of february?

Comment: You really need to have some culture to start from when converting a string to a date. Otherwise, as @M4N stated, you'll get ambiguous results.

Comment: That is right. In fact I know the format of the original string. So using TryParseExact as proposed by Habib I could successfully convert it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` or `Datetime.ParseExact` with multiple formats like:

```
string dateStr = "20/02/2014 1:41:57 PM";
string[] dateFormats = new[]
    {

        "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
        "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
    };

DateTime dt;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr,
                            dateFormats,
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            DateTimeStyles.None,
                            out dt))
{
    //valid dates for formats
}
else
{
    //invalid date
}
```

the problem with this approach is that it would give you inconsistent results with strings like `10/02/2014 1:41:57 PM`, The above code would parse it as 10th Feb 2014, not as `October 2nd 2014`, to avoid this you can customize your client side to return date in specific format and then parse accordingly.

Comment: Great. Using this code I was able to resolve my problem. In fact I have a way to define the format that will come for the string, so using this parsing method it successfully does the parsing. Thanks!

Comment: now I selected this answer. let me know if it is not ok.

Comment: in fact I wanted to select both your and Jonesy answer as ok. so first I clicked yours and then his, but did not notice it unselected yours.

Comment: @user2974961, accepting or not accepting a question is totally upto you :)

Answer (score 0):

you want [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

i.e.

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse(stringDate, out dt)
{
    //successful datetime conversion
}
```

if you know the string will be one of several exact formats, you can use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass in a string array of each format (the second overload).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried your code but it is not parsing both formats as well, just one. The difference is that instead of throwing an exception it doesn't enter the if. But it still doesn't creates the datetime object I need. I wouldn't like to go with the string array or each format because I don't know all the formats that will come. It could be many. thanks

Comment: Just a correction... I am able to identify the format of the string, so using the tryparseexact method worked. Thanks!